# SDL2 - VSYNC active, but tearing at specific window height

Tags: c++, windows, sdl-2

I am using SDL2 in windowed mode on Windows 7 64bit to create a small game.

I get tearing at the same height of the window despite having VSYNC active. The weird thing is that the movement in itself is fluid, but there is this line, about 50px from the bottom, where tearing is noticeable. It always stays there, without moving or anything.

The weird thing is that if I crate a smaller window, I get tearing at exactly the same height from the bottom.

I tried taking screens of it but it doesn't show the tearing.

I have no idea if this is a problem of SDL2, a problem with Windows, a problem with my pc or a problem in my source file. I have tried looking online for a solution but I could not find anything like this problem.

It is a first for me since I have been playing with a lot of SDL games in the past in windowed mode and none had this problem.

Here is a snippet of the source I have been using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 400;
const int  SCREEN_HEIGHT = 300;

bool init( SDL_Window** window, SDL_Renderer** renderer ) {

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(*window, 0, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    int flags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
    IMG_Init(flags);

    return true;
}

void close( SDL_Texture** image, SDL_Window** window ) {
    SDL_DestroyTexture( *image );
    *image = NULL;

    SDL_DestroyWindow( *window );
    *window = NULL;

    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture* image = NULL;
    const SDL_Rect rect = { 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 200 };
    SDL_Rect rectImage, rectImageOriginal;
    int w, h;

    SDL_QueryTexture(image, NULL, NULL, &w, &h);
    rectImage = { 0, 0, w, h };
    rectImageOriginal = rectImage;

    init( window, renderer );
    image = IMG_LoadTexture( renderer, path );

    while (running) {

        [... here I move rectImage ...]

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 200, 0, 0, 255);

        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, NULL);

        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, image, &rectImageOriginal, &rectImage);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    close(&image, &window);
}
```

Comment: An update: I have a dual monitor setup, one with 1920x1080 resolution, the other with 1600x900 resolution. Both screens update at 60hz.

The problem of the tearing appearing always at the same height happens on the 1920x1080 monitor. If I drag the window on the other monitor, the tearing is different. Here the tearing line is moving upwards slowly.

The first thing I would think of is that there is a syncing problem, but I don't get why the tearing is different on each monitor if the framerate is the same. Someone help :(

Comment: Another update: I have inserter some code to check the FPS of the window when vsynced. It came out to be a stable 56. This is not the monitor's refresh rate which is 60hz. This explains the tearing I experience, but it is really weird. It looks like the vsync doesn't actually sync properly. What may be the cause for this?

Comment: Maybe the drawing frame is not keeping up with the sync rate of 60Hz